# ¿Queria habilitar el modulo "mod_rewrite" con el servidor mamp del mac?

Tags: apache

Hola buenas tarde queria habilitar el modulo mod_rewrite del servidor MAMP del mac.

tengo el un archivo `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/master-php/proyecto-php-poo/error/

RewriteCond  %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1$&action=$2
</IfModule>
```

He mirado también el httpd.conf para ver si algún modulo estaba deshabitado estaba habilitado pero sigue sin funcionar quería como quiero que funcione

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

El problemas es que queria saber si hay  alguna otra forma para saber si se puede habilitar el modulo rewrite en el mamp estaba buscado información y solo encuentro el wampserve y el xamp pero del servidor mamp no encuentro nada . Lo mas cerca que he buscado es eso que he puesto.

Gracias Ante mano .

Comment: Hola, ¿has probado [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592215/install-and-configure-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-on-mac-os-x-for-zend-framework-2) solución? En la misma no sólo se habilita el módulo `mod_rewrite` sino que se habilita `php` (aunque imagino que ya lo tienes habilitado) y se cambian los permisos de `AllowOverride` al valor de `all` en la sección `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">` o donde tengas tu directorio para documentos web. Prueba eso a ver si te funciona. Saludos

Comment: Eso era lo que me ha faltado hacer estaba en bien

Comment: Voy ha responder la respuesta  como lo he echo para que las persona que tenga el mismo fallo lo ponga

Comment: Excelente. Intenta explicarlo con detalle y así tu publicación tendrá calidad. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola buenas tarde voy ha dejar como lo he solucionado el problema por completo para los que tiene el mismo problemas que he tenido yo.
Para activar el modulo rewrite para usara las url limpias de tu programa

Para empezar  vamos al fichero donde tienes el MAMP/CONFI/APACHE
En el archivo httpd.confi busca el siguiente modulo:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

fijate bien si no esta comentado con una # si lo tiene se lo quita luego el siguiente paso es ver el directorio de opciones

**AllorwOverride en None**  en **All** como lo tengo yo

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Por el final en el archivo del programa de configuracion .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/master-php/proyecto-php-poo/error/

RewriteCond  %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</IfModule>
```

En caso que el RewriteRule lo tenga de esta manera 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1$&action=$2`Pon lo como lo tengo yo en la imagen anterior